# PHP formatted email doesn't send PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am trying to send a personalized message to the customer via PHP formatted e-mail with some PHP code in it. But, for some spectacular reason, I am unable to send `$_POST['message']`. But other variables are sent and visible.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
function set_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Whittington Barge - QR';
$body = '<html><head></head><body>
<h1>Here is your Voucher!</h1>
<h3>Test personalized message: '.$_POST['message'].'<h3>
<p>Feel free to save it to your phone and show us when you arrive!</p>
<img src="'.$_POST['image'].'"></img></body></html>';

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body );

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
?>
```

In result, I get [this e-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa2Y3.png).

I have tried pretty much everything I know. It is held on a Wordpress website as well.

Comment: Close your `h3` tag, change `<h3>Test personalized message: '.$_POST['message'].'<h3>` to `<h3>Test personalized message: '.$_POST['message'].'</h3>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h3>` tag is open/unclosed.

Close your `<h3>` tag,

change: 
`<h3>Test personalized message: '.$_POST['message'].'<h3>`

to: `<h3>Test personalized message: '.$_POST['message'].'</h3>`

Comment: It does't even send a `<h3>` string... What could be a problem?

Comment: Have you made the suggested change?

Comment: Can you echo/print out the `$body` variable before sending the mail?

Comment: And what is the value of `$_POST['message']`?

Comment: It does echo full message, but it doesn't send only one line of email. Could it be because of cache? The value at the moment is TEST MESSAGE, but it can be whatever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135846/discussion-between-justbaron-and-marks-gniteckis).